# Unable to authenticate REST API request on dialogflow v2 and v2beta1

Tags: c#, authentication, dialogflow-es, gcloud

[Authorisation issue when we use this code to connect to dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kE8Z.png)

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V2/V2beta1 of the API relies on a Google Cloud Platform Service Account for authentication, instead of the previously used client and developer access tokens.

Generating the Service Account key
In order to use the V2 API, you will need to create a new Service Account and obtain a private key associated with the Service Account. The key is downloaded as a JSON file upon creation of the Service Account.

**Caution: Your project will have an existing service account, but this should not be altered. For additional client and developer API access, you should create a new service account.**

1. Please first login into your Dialogflow console and select the appropriate project (only if you have multiple projects). Go to the settings of Dialogflow and click on the service account link as shown below:

**Note: Also make sure to enable beta features and APIs.**

2. Now this will redirect you to your GCP service account page. From there you need to click on  navigation menu (Top Left Corner) and select APIs & Services > Credentials.
3. Now Click on Create credentials and select Service account key.
   Note: Please note that if you have multiple projects linked to your GCP choose the appropriate project from the drop down and choose your project from the all tab rather than recent tab.
4. Now Choose New service account from the drop down list. Give a name to this service account and please make sure to select the role to Owner. Select JSON (by default selected).
5. Now click on Create Button. Your JSON key file will be downloaded to your system.
6. Now use this JSON key file to authenticate your requests.

Now download V2/V2Beta1 API from nuget package manager on visual studio.

Please refer this code:

```
var rFile = GoogleCredential.FromFile(jsonkeyfilepath);
        var scopeC = rFile.CreateScoped(DialogflowService.Scope.CloudPlatform);
        var response = new DialogflowService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = scopeC,
            ApplicationName = "project-name-here"
        }).Projects.Agent.Sessions.DetectIntent(
                    new GoogleCloudDialogflowV2beta1DetectIntentRequest
                    {
                        QueryInput = new GoogleCloudDialogflowV2beta1QueryInput
                        {
                            Text = new GoogleCloudDialogflowV2beta1TextInput
                            {
                                Text = "your text here",
                                LanguageCode = "en-US"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    $"projects/projectid/agent/sessions/34141414")
                    .Execute();
        return (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.QueryResult));
```